# Subtract the mean from panel data?

Tags: r, panel-data, polynomial

I'm working with some panel style data and I was wonder if it makes sense to subtract the mean from my predictors as a whole or to do it by year. So lets say I was doing a pooled regression of some panel data:

```
brand  year  y  x1  x2
----------------------
brand_1 2013 12 123 63
brand_1 2014 12 45  345
brand_1 2015 53 23  345
brand_2 2013 35 13  65
brand_2 2014 74 45  35
brand_2 2015 47 23  45
.
.
.
brand_n 2013 54 155 600
brand_n 2014 54 15  38
brand_n 2015 23 333  32
```

If I were to add a quadratic term into the model generally one is suppose to subtract the mean from the the original variable for interpretation sake. Should the mean be subtracted by year or just overall?

```
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2), data = df)
```